# Import all headers through a single header?

Tags: ios, objective-c, import, header-files

I see in many frameworks, they have something like a `Globals.h` which simply just imports all header files. Making it very easy elsewhere to just import that single `Globals.h` header to access everything.

I'm not using any specific framework, I'm just working on a standard, relatively simple project. I'm doing a lot of importing and I started to think can't I just apply this technique?

Can I? Or will it lead to potential problems? Like recursive importing? Just wondered if there were any particular methods or situations you would use this in or things to watch out for?

Thanks.

Comment: Objective-C has the #import preprocessor instruction. This does almost the same as #include, but it also notes internally which file has already been included. The #import line is only replaced by the contents of the named file for the first time it is encountered. Every time after that it is just ignored.So just do like many frameworks, #import is smart enough to get things done!

Comment: There are very few cases where an umbrella header makes sense in a smaller project that need not be as connected as a framework.  Header imports are basically text replacement at compile time, so it may actually increase build time if you import this thing gratuitously.

Comment: Got it! Two very valid and useful bits of information. Worth a tick as an answer. Essentially, it shouldn't break anything as #import is smart, but assess whether an umbrella header is worthwhile.

Comment: I'd like  to add to the above. #import is smart, but it's not that smart. Keep that in mind :)

Comment: Based off what you've all said, I'll keep it to widely required classes, those less frequently required can be left out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this inside a framework makes sense. You don't want the end user to import a bunch of classes so you instruct him to import just one. That header will take care of the rest.
Doing something similar inside a project can help you simplify things if you always import a.h b.h and c.h together, creating a header file called abAndC.h would also make sense.

As a side note I always import my Constants.h in my pch file to avoid importing it through my project.

Answer (score 0):

Importing everything everywhere doesn't make sense to me. If that file won't be included in the `pch` file it can harm a compile time and moreover you expose so many class details everywhere - that should be considered as a bad practice. The file with a global imports is a good idea if it contains only a very popular headers (I would put there imports for classes that occurs in, let's say, 30% classes or so). Then I would include that global importing header into `pch` file as it not only makes it visible everywhere in the app but also helps to reduce compiling time. Moreover remember to use modules for standard libraries wherever it is possible (it also reduces compile time not only in case of including from `pch` file). Except the popular classes I wouldn't expose implementation details in header file if it is not necessary - instead use forward declaration.